# Is there a way to get programmatically notified when an OPAM package is updated at opam.ocaml.org?

Tags: ocaml, travis-ci, opam

We are trying to build into an Open Source ocaml project a way to automatically kick off a Travis CI build & test session when any of the 3rd party OPAM packages the project depends on get changed. If there was some clean way to get a change notification, then programmatically we could touch a file in a test branch and do a pull request which would start the Travis CI process to test compatibility so that our end users don't trip over the issue. We're trying to avoid wasting OPAM resources polling.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

`opam.ocaml.org` is a mirror of the OPAM repo `https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository`, therefore you can periodically pull it and check the new commits.

You may have to be careful of silent source code change of packages, since their sources are out of the OPAM repo.  If packages are OPAM registered without their checksums, you have to periodically check their sources themselves, too.